# My collision detection does not work for Java graphics

Tags: java, collision-detection

```
int border=30;
boolean balldown=true;
boolean ballright=true;
int bounce=0;


public void moveBall(){



    if (balldown==true){
        //y++; 
        rect3.b++;

    }


    if (balldown==false){
        y--;
        rect3.b--;
    }
    //y==getHeight()-border
    if(rect3.b==getHeight()-border){


        balldown=false;
        bounce++;
    }
    //y==0
    if(rect3.b==0){


        balldown=true;
        bounce++;
    }

    if (ballright==true){
        x++; 
        rect3.a++;
    }

    if (ballright==false){
        x--;
        rect3.a--;
    }
    //x==getWidth
        if(colision==true){


        ballright=false;
        bounce++;

    }
    colision=false;

    //x==0
    //rect3.bounds2()==rect1.bounds()
    if(colision==true){


        ballright=true;
        bounce++;

    }

    }
   /* if(rect3.a==getWidth()){
        ballright=false;
    }
    if(rect3.a==0){
        ballright=true;
    }*/
}

   // int a=0;
   // int b=0;
    //int width=30;
   // int height=200;

    rect rect1;
    rect rect2;
    rect rect3;
    Timer time;
    boolean colision=false;

    public Pong() {
        rect1 = new rect(0,0);
        rect2 = new rect(977,0);
        rect3=new rect(40,40);
        time=new Timer(5,this);
        time.start();
    }




public class rect{
    int a,b;

    public rect(int startA, int startB){
        a=startA;
        b=startB;
    }

    public Rectangle bounds(){

    return (new Rectangle(a,b,30,200));
}
    public Rectangle bounds2(){

    return (new Rectangle(a,b,30,30));
    }
}




@Override
public void paint(Graphics g){


    super.paint(g);

    Graphics2D g2d=(Graphics2D) g;
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 1080, 760);


    g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
   // g.fillOval(x, y, 30, 30);
   g2d.fillRect(rect3.a, rect3.b, 30, 30);

    g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g2d.fillRect(rect1.a, rect1.b, 30, 200);

    g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g2d.fillRect(rect2.a, rect2.b, 30, 200);

    g2d.fillRect(520, 0, 10, 760);

    if (colision==true)
        g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 20));
        g.drawString("Colision",350, 50);



     g.setFont(new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 20));

        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);

        g.drawString("BOUNCES: "+bounce, 40, 20);
}


public void colision(){

    Rectangle rectangle1=rect1.bounds();
    Rectangle rectangle2=rect2.bounds();
    Rectangle rectangle3=rect3.bounds2();

        if(rectangle3.intersects(rectangle1))
            colision=true;
        else
            colision=false;

        if(rectangle3.intersects(rectangle2))
            colision=true;

        else
            colision=false;


}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        moveBall();
        colision();
        repaint();
```

So basically my if statement that uses intersects never returns true whenever my ball hits the rectangle on the side. Also in my moveball method is supposed supposed to "bounce" in the other direction whenever those bounds meet but it does not work and simply passes trough with no collision detection even. Did I implement it wrong? When I checked with a system.out.print it kept returning the message like 2 times per second or even faster. Im a java beginner to dont scream at me for obvious mistakes and the bad structure. Thanks

Comment: if there is a collision between 1 and 3 but not between 2 and 3, `collision`will be false. Weird behaviour.  Fix the indentation and remove all those empty lines to make your code easier to read

Comment: I tried doing this if(rectangle3.intersects(rectangle1))
                colision=true;
            else
            if(rectangle3.intersects(rectangle2))
                colision=true;
            else 
               colision=false;

But it still does not work

Comment: Any ideas on what I can do to fix this?